# Hibernate mapping - map that contains a map

Tags: hibernate

Most of the time, it is pretty obvious to map the collections using Hibernate. However, at times, it is really confusing to use the Hibernate mapping for advanced collections.

Especially, how we can map this particular collection, say:

```
Map <img_name , Map<dimension,file>>
```

using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible that value of Map is Map or Collection. I don't know where exactly this is pointed out in Hibernate documentation, but in JPA specification it is written following way:

> The map key and the map value independently can each be a basic type,
>   an embeddable class, or an entity.

You have to modify structure, for example presenting dimension and file as an entity.